# Fixing IndexOutOfBounds Exception in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to make a String ArrayList that stores all the words in a sentence. Currently, I'm trying to achieve this by finding the indexes of the spaces and storing that in an array. The arraylist for spaces works, however, the arraylist for the words does not. The values for the string arraylist is the substring between the indexes of two spaces. Please help.

```
for(int x = 0; x < spaces.size(); x++) {
    words.add(post.substring(spaces.get(x) + 1, spaces.get(x + 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `x` is `size()-1`, then you'll call `x+1` which will be equal to `size()` which is not a valid index

Since you are looking one index ahead, only loop until less than `size()-1`:

```
for(int x = 0; x < spaces.size()-1; x++) {
    words.add(post.substring(spaces.get(x) + 1, spaces.get(x + 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this.

Suppose you have the following String with words:

```
stringWithWords = "This is my string";
```

First you can split the String into an array of words:

```
String wordsArray[] = stringWithWords(" ");
```

After that, you can convert the array to an ArrayList:

```
List<String> wordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
wordsArrayList = Arrays.asList(wordsArray);
```